# How to get DirectShow device list with ffmpeg in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, directshow

I'm trying to get dshow device list with ffmpeg. I cannot get it but ffmpeg gets it by its own. Here is the code. It returns AVERROR(ENOSYS) for avdevice_list_input_sources. But avformat_open_input prints all devices. How can I get dshow devices and options in c++ code.

```
    avdevice_register_all();
    AVInputFormat *iformat = av_find_input_format("dshow");
    printf("========Device Info=============\n");
    AVDeviceInfoList *device_list = NULL;
    AVDictionary* options = NULL;
    //av_dict_set(&options, "list_devices", "true", 0);
    int result = avdevice_list_input_sources(iformat, NULL, options, &device_list);

    if (result < 0)
        printf("Error Code:%s\n", av_err2str(result));//Returns -40 AVERROR(ENOSYS)
    else printf("Devices count:%d\n", result);

    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVDictionary* options2 = NULL;
    av_dict_set(&options2, "list_devices", "true", 0);
    avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, NULL, iformat, &options2);
    printf("================================\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"We" haven't plumbed libav to return the device list yet.  So it's either parse the output of `ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -list_devices true -i dummy` or enumerate them yourself using dshow api's:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow#Howtoprogrammaticallyenumeratedevices

Comment: Okay, i intended to parse the output however how can i get output into a buffer rather then stdout. Output of  `avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, NULL, iformat, &options);`

Comment: av_log_set_callback apparently http://libav-user.ffmpeg.narkive.com/BOPqn51D/how-to-capture-libav-log-messages-and-save-them-to-a-file I would just system call out to ffmpeg.exe and parse its stdout :)